# Sorcery - current_users not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

I'm using Sorcery for authentication in my Rails 4 app, and I can't get the current_users method to work.  I keep getting the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_users' for #<UsersController:0x007fc7b5a75588>
```

View:

```
Currently active users: <%= current_users_list %>
```

Application_controller.rb :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_users_list

  private
  def not_authenticated
    redirect_to login_url, :alert => "First log in to view this page."
  end

  def current_users_list
    current_users.map {|u| u.email}.join(", ")
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have the activity logging module enabled.

Change your initializer to include it :

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.submodules = [:activity_logging, whatever_else]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the [wiki guide](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Activity-logging) like I did, then the submodule will be added automatically. The problem is then twofold:

1. You need to restart your rails server
2. You need to ensure that you set up a username field OR change it to email

`current_users.map {|u| u.username}.join(", ")`

`current_users.map {|u| u.email}.join(", ")`